# Errors working with bokeh in javascript model

Tags: javascript, bokeh

I'm trying to work with Bokeh JS implementation i.e. trying to use the JS API of bokeh to display glyphs. I followed the instructions provided in bokeh documentation, but the page error's out. For example var plt = Bokeh. Plotting is undefined. What's going wrong?

I have included all the CSS/JS files as indicated in the documentation. Below is the code copied from the documentation - trying to get it working

Can someone with bokehjs experience help?

```js
$(function() {

  var plt = Bokeh.Plotting;
  console.log(Bokeh.Plotting);

  // set up some data
  var M = 100;
  var xx = [];
  var yy = [];
  var colors = [];
  var radii = [];
  for (var y = 0; y <= M; y += 4) {
    for (var x = 0; x <= M; x += 4) {
      xx.push(x);
      yy.push(y);
      colors.push(plt.color(50 + 2 * x, 30 + 2 * y, 150));
      radii.push(Math.random() * 0.4 + 1.7)
    }
  }

  // create a data source
  var source = new Bokeh.ColumnDataSource({
    data: {
      x: xx,
      y: yy,
      radius: radii,
      colors: colors
    }
  });

  // make the plot and add some tools
  var tools = "pan,crosshair,wheel_zoom,box_zoom,reset,save";
  var p = plt.figure({
    title: "Colorful Scatter",
    tools: tools
  });

  // call the circle glyph method to add some circle glyphs
  var circles = p.circle({
    field: "x"
  }, {
    field: "y"
  }, {
    source: source,
    radius: radii,
    fill_color: colors,
    fill_alpha: 0.6,
    line_color: null
  });

  // add the plot to a document and display it
  // var doc = new Bokeh.Document();
  // doc.add_root(plt);
  // var div = $("#plot");
  // cosole.log(div);
  // Bokeh.embed.add_document_standalone(doc, div);

  plt.show(p);



});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-0.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-widgets-0.12.4.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-0.12.4.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-widgets-0.12.4.min.css">

<div id="plot">

</div>
```

Comment: Turns out, Bokeh has changed the JS APIs since 0.12.1 So the above code works for <=0.12.1 but for more recent releases the JS code breaks. The documentation has not changed though. Hoping the documentation is updated soon.

Comment: If you have an answer, please post it and mark it accepted. This may help future visitors.

Comment: Thanks, will do it

Answer (score 1):

Turns out, Bokeh has changed the JS APIs since 0.12.1 So the above code works for <=0.12.1 but for more recent releases the JS code breaks. The documentation has not changed though. Hoping the documentation is updated soon

Comment: Do you have any more details or a source for this? I'm currently trying to migrate some code to 0.12.4 and I just can't find anything after the restructuring. Is there an open issue on github? Did you manage to port your example to 0.12.4? Due to the lack of documentation, Bokehjs 0.12.4 is almost unusable for me.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I was able to get BokehJS 0.12.4 to work. The [release notes of 0.12.2](http://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/releases/0.12.2.html#bokehjs-api-changes) contain a small note that the BokehJS API has been split into its own bundle. So when migrating from pre-0.12.2 to a recent version, it is necessary to add the following javascript

```
https://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-api-0.12.4.min.js
```

in addition to the existing `bokeh-0.12.4.min.js` and `bokeh-widgets-0.12.4.min.js`. After adding this file to your example it works. Unfortunately, this information didn't make it into the official BokehJS documentation yet.

```js
$(function() {
  var plt = Bokeh.Plotting;

  // set up some data
  var M = 100;
  var xx = [];
  var yy = [];
  var colors = [];
  var radii = [];
  for (var y = 0; y <= M; y += 4) {
    for (var x = 0; x <= M; x += 4) {
      xx.push(x);
      yy.push(y);
      colors.push(plt.color(50 + 2 * x, 30 + 2 * y, 150));
      radii.push(Math.random() * 0.4 + 1.7)
    }
  }

  // create a data source
  var source = new Bokeh.ColumnDataSource({
    data: {
      x: xx,
      y: yy,
      radius: radii,
      colors: colors
    }
  });

  // make the plot and add some tools
  var tools = "pan,crosshair,wheel_zoom,box_zoom,reset,save";
  var p = plt.figure({
    title: "Colorful Scatter",
    tools: tools
  });

  // call the circle glyph method to add some circle glyphs
  var circles = p.circle({
    field: "x"
  }, {
    field: "y"
  }, {
    source: source,
    radius: radii,
    fill_color: colors,
    fill_alpha: 0.6,
    line_color: null
  });

  plt.show(p);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-0.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-api-0.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-widgets-0.12.4.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-0.12.4.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-widgets-0.12.4.min.css">

<div id="plot"></div>
```